# How to fix wacky spacing with tabu and dcolumn?

Tags: tabu, dcolumn

How do I fix this wacky spacing with `tabu` and `dcolumn`?

Am I missing out on some best practices here?

Thanks much!!

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}to \linewidth{l*4{d{2}}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Long long long heading A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Long long long heading B} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} \\
\midrule
Variable Description    & 1.12233       & 1.234         & 0.567         & 0.681         \\
                        & (0.0123)      & (0.01234)     & (0.012)       & (0.01234)     \\
\midrule
$N$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{123456} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{123456} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{123456} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{123456} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of MWE]

Comment: `tabu` is buggy and not maintained, so better is not to use it. Instead it you try t use `tabularx` or new package `tabularray`, for columns is good option to use `S` columns defined in `siunitx` packagew

Comment: don't use tabu at all, dcolumn is a viable alterative to siunitx but the latter has more features, but if you do use dcolumn you need to use a reasonable specification. `d{2}` means format a column that has numbers with _at most 2 decimal places_ all your numbers have more than 2 decimal places

Answer (score 3):

An example how you can set your table using `tabularray` and `siunitx` packages:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty =,
    input-close-uncertainty=,
    table-align-text-post=false
        }

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={l *{4}{X[c,si={table-format={(}1.5}]}},
             measure=vbox
             }
    \toprule
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  
        {{{Long long long heading A}}} 
                &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  
                                {{{Long long long heading B}}}    
                                        &               \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-3} \cmidrule[l]{4-5}
    & {{{(1)}}} & {{{(2)}}} & {{{(3)}}} & {{{(4)}}}     \\
    \midrule
Variable Description    
    & 1.12233   & 1.234     & 0.567     & 0.681         \\
    & (0.0123)  & (0.01234) & (0.012)   & (0.01234)     \\
    \midrule
$N$ & {{{123456}}} 
                & {{{123456}}} 
                            & {{{123456}}} 
                                        & {{{123456}}}  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which (a) uses `tabular` instead of `tabu`and (b) replaces the ill-conceived `d{2}` column specification with alternatives that range from `d{2.4}` to `d{2.6}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,DIV=12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} l d{2.5} d{2.6} d{2.4} d{2.6} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading A} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Heading B} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} \\
\midrule
Variable Description    & 1.12233       & 1.234         & 0.567         & 0.681         \\
                        & (0.0123)      & (0.01234)     & (0.012)       & (0.01234)     \\
\midrule
$N$ & \mc{123456} & \mc{123456} & \mc{123456} & \mc{123456} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```